# Is this funny way of saying things some dialect?

Tags: topolect, slang

> 本身明明长患上丑还说[...]那鸣一个惨呀!

长患 should be 长相 and 鸣 should be 叫, but they appear too many times that the possibility of them being typos is close to nil.

> [...]以是在贬低他人的时辰就出格不留人情，以是咱们见到这类人时可以绝不夷由地上往打。

Again, normally we would say 于是 instead of 以是, 时候 instead of 时辰, 毫不犹豫 instead of 绝不夷由, and I think 格外 instead of 出格. I don't even understand what's 上往打: is 上往 上前?

> 但是不管曩昔几多年

I know Cantonese makes extensive use of 几多, but other sentences don't look like they're Cantonese. And isn't 曩昔 archaic? The reason I find this article so funny and interesting is that it is so colloquial, yet at the same time so archaic or formal.

> 最厌恶掉臂及男子体面的女人

What? 掉臂? As in [自在](http://baike.baidu.com/view/7333658.htm)?

> 眼望着本身岁数一点点年夜了

Can you really use 年夜 as a verb like that?

> 碰着如许的人

This sounds rather formal and archaic.

Of course I am not endorsing these statements or anything, just saw them somewhere on the internet and find them amusing. Are these sentences written in some dialects/topolects or an unusual form of standard Chinese? Or are they internet slang?

Comment: I've seen similar phenomenon (half dialectal, half made-up language) in more than one literature works, none of which is from famous writers. I am curious to know if it's a widely known style and/or the theory behind it.

Comment: Could you share the source or more complete paragraphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

我在网上找了一下，你提到的这篇文章标题是《死都没人爱的9种女人》，事实上它有“正常中文”版本的原文：
[image]

其实还可以搜索到一篇内容十分类似的文章《十种汉子该暴挨，你属于那一种？》，前者应该只是把后者内容当中的“男人”替换成了“女人”。而后者2006年左右就出现在网络上了，这种类型的文章作为段子实在是很过时。现在的大多数网民应该都不会觉得这篇文章有趣。

[image]

至于你提到的这种“奇怪的中文”的版本，确实网上可以搜索到：

[image]

这应当是通过某种类似于在线翻译的方式由电脑自动转换的，在网上还可以搜索到一些类似风格的文章。我不清楚这些网站在转载时进行这种转换的原因。不过显然这并不是为了有趣，也不是标准汉语的特殊形式，也不是所谓网络语言。应该说，就是网络上的一种信息垃圾。不用去深究，也不要把它作为学习中文的参考。

Comment: 转换的原因会不会是为了防止抄袭侦测？

Comment: @GaoWeiwei Seems you're right. Found these 同义词替换/伪原创工具 http://baike.baidu.com/view/2537897.htm

Comment: @NS.X. The software ain't half bad, reads somewhat like human (though you need a human to write something first). It's my first time reading this kind of writing, so I apologize for asking something 过时 and not really about the Chinese language.

Answer (score 1):

长患 (cháng huàn) means having an unfortunate fate since a long time, here the particular fate of being ugly.

The rest of your concerns are rather standard wordings, although not the most common ones. A word like 时光 would indicate topolect (Wu), but only with different pronouns (阿拉 instead of 咱们). It could of course be a minor Mandarin dialect, or just internet slang.

上往打 is a bit peculiar, though.

Comment: I feel like the author of the funny sentences just picked up a thesaurus and grabbed whatever synonyms there are to the more standard wordings. Maybe they do this for comical effects.

Comment: Could be, similar to English speaking kids flavoring texts with anacronistic stuff from Shakespeare and Chaucer. Chinese forums are replete with 阿弥陀佛, 伯爵, 状元 and such nonsense.